# Adding Doctrine to a legacy database, not null join fields cause integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am attempting to retrofit Doctrine over a large existing database. Having an issue with how that database handles foreign keys. As a cut-down example we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `org_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `orgs` (
  `org_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`org_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then an entity matching that table:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Org")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="org_id", referencedColumnName="org_id")
     */
    protected $org;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @TORM\able(name="orgs")
 */
class Org {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $org_id;
}
```

It is legitimate for a user to not be linked to an org. In the database the user would look like:

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "org_id": 0
}
```

However when trying to insert a new row:

```
$user = new User;
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

The error appears:

```
PDO Exception: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (created, org_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["2020-12-11 14:41:27", null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'org_id' cannot be null
```

So it seems that where Doctrine sees there being no relation it inserts `null`. I can therefore resolve this issue by *changing* the `org_id` column to `NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`. However:

1. this means there will be rows with 0 and rows with `null` which both indicate no relation
2. the existing application that uses this table expects `int` back, meaning a lot of code would need to be refactored (not to mention queries that will treat null and 0 very differently)

I imagine retrofitting Doctrine to existing databases must be something people do, so I am wondering if there is another solution that doesn't involve changes at the database level. It seems like some sort of post-processor that caught null values and converted them to 0 would work but I am unsure how to implement this.

Comment: Is `@ID` (uppercase) intentional?

Comment: Does your orgs table have an org with an id of 0?  If not then fooling around with changing nulls to zero is not going to help.  I'm guessing trying to add a '0 org' might cause it's own set of problems with other code.  It's easy to design databases that Doctrine cannot handle.  Interchanging zeros and nulls is one of them.

Comment: @Ocramius I'm uncertain; checking the docs I can see they use `@Id` so it's possibly a typo. Will it be breaking anything?

Comment: @Cerad it doesn't no; this is a legacy database that I am trying to retrofit Doctrine to; I did mention this in the question. However my question is also assuming that this is probably not a unique case - I am unlikely the first to attempt to use Doctrine on an older database with a design that wasn't done with Doctrine in mind, and thus it seems likely somebody will have a way to make this work

Comment: @Ocramius I've now updated `@ID` in my models to `@Id` but it doesn't seem to have affected anything as far as I can see

Comment: May I ask whoever has downvoted this question to give me some explanation as to how I can improve it? As far as I can see the question poses a clear problem along with the research I've done thus far; I do not imagine I'm the first person attempting to retrofit Doctrine to a database with these constraints and thus a working answer to this may benefit a lot of people.

Comment: @M1ke is there any reason why you can’t run a one-off query to de-assign `0` to all those existing users and set their `org_id` to `null`. Fixing the DB schema would probably be a better option than mashing the code to work around it..?

Comment: @nealio82 yeah, setting the fields to nullable and no other changes currently causes hundreds of test fails. Mainly due to how SQL handles things like IN and NOT IN when nulls are present, but also due to PDO returns where subsequent functions use int casts (expecting 0 or positive int) and now get nulls. It's potentially possible to fix all the code, but it's not 100% test covered and I think there's a lot of complex SQL queries that might exhibit issues.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
$default = $em->find('Org', 0);

$user = new User;
$user->setDefaultOrg($default);
$user->created = new DateTime();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Then in your User Class

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User {

  protected $default_org;

  /**
   * @ORM\ID
   * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  protected $user_id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
   */ 
  public $created;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Org", cascade={"persist"})
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="org_id", referencedColumnName="org_id")
   */
  protected $org;

   /**
    * @ORM\PrePersist()
    */
   public function fixLegacyOrg()
   {
      if (is_null($this->org)) {
        $this->org = $this->default_org;
      }
   }

  public function setDefaultOrg(Org $org)
  {
      $this->default_org = $org;
  }
}
```

Depends on your testing need you could inject into the constructor (ideally just the Org not the whole entity manager)

as a side note for this to work you need to add the AutoIncrement on the table query from above (I imagine its a copy / paste error)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I imagine it will involve me having to couple entities to the entity manager, but that's not a bad price to pay for being able to use Doctrine without rewiring an entire application and database.

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working as the `find()` method returns null due to an org with ID 0 not existing

Comment: I've tried using other listeners such as PreFlush and PostPersist to force org_id to 0, but it seems to get overwritten with null somewhere inside the unit of work. Trying to figure out where so I can manually override it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this but I imagine the solution could upset some people. I'll preface this with the following: this is a solution for when you absolutely cannot update your schema to use nullable fields in your foreign key relations. For example in my case there's hundreds of places where database entities are used where an "empty" join field is expected to be an int, rather than a nullable int.

In this case the solution that works, and is definitely against Doctrine best practices, is to pre-set "empty" versions of your entities in the Entity Manager prior to running any queries:

```
/** @var EntityManager $em **/
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$uow->createEntity(Org::class, ['org_id' => 0]);
```

For each case where you have this "0 instead of nullable" field on a join you can add this to the Entity Manager. It's likely also required in your models to handle this with null values. E.g. in `User`

```
public function getOrg(): ?Org{
  $org = $this->org;
  // Expected null condition
  if (!$org){
    return null;
  }
  
  // UoW hacked "null" entity
  if (!$org->org_id){
    return null;
  }

  return $org;
}
```

This mechanism avoids leaking the entity manager directly into models but does add noise inside the models having to check for these "nullable" entities. I am unsure how this works in relation to more complex DDL queries, but it works to get Doctrine usable and I'd suggest anyone employing it could then run separate projects to progressively remove each fake entity by making it's foreign key field nullable and modifying the application to support this.